# Полное название

Tags: прописная-строчная

На вопрос: "Скажите, с какой буквы (прописной или строчной) писать название Л(л)итературный музей, К(к)раеведческий музей, если в полном виде названия звучат так: Нижегородский литературный музей, Пензенский государственный краеведческий музей?" -- Справочная служба русского языка отвечает: "Эти сочетания пишутся строчными буквами".

Но у Лопатина:

Государственная Третьяковская галерея, Государственный академический Большой театр, Московский Художественный академический театр, Государственный Русский музей (и неофициальные их названия: Третьяковская галерея, Большой театр, Художественный театр, Русский музей);

Тогда, следуя этому, следует писать неофициальное название Нижегородского литературного музея как Литературный музей?

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, вопрос о другом. Почему в названии "Нижегородский литературный музей" слово "литературный" пишется со строчной буквы, а "Государственная Третьяковская галерея" и подобные наименования центральных учреждений имеют прописное написание вторых слов (Третьяковская галерея, Большой театр, Русский музей и т.п.)? Думаю, что дело здесь в том, что сегодня называют "брендовым" названием.  Официальное название "Государственный Русский музей", но в обиходе это знаменитое учреждение культуры называют короче - "Русский музей". То же с "брендовыми" именами "Третьяковская галерея, Художественный театр и т.д.". Этим объясняется и тот факт, что и в официальных названиях этих культурных центров вторые слова тоже пишутся со строчной буквы

Comment: В Пензе не был, а Нижегородский литературный - таки себе бренд, пусть и не такой как Большой театр... Горький, однако...

Answer (score 1):

Да. *Литературный музей* - с загланой первое слово. Насколько понимаю, такое написание никто не оспаривает (если ошибаюсь - дайте знать). 
Но уж рекомендации "Справки" и Лопатина полностью совпадают. Непонятно, почему вы предпослали "но" последнему.

Comment: Розенталя, можно сказать, оспаривает Грамота, так как рекомендует писать со строчной, а не с прописной.

Comment: А, пардон, там действительно двусмысленость... 
Это я не вчитался, настолько был уверен, что понимаю, о чем они говорят.
Но я думаю, Грамота просто по инерции выдала обычную формулировку. Я сейчас посмотрю на другие "грамотные" ответы, просто пояню, там этот вопрос не раз поднимался.

Answer (score 0):

Художественных  галерей много,  Третьяковская  -  одна. Так  же  Большой  и  Малый  театры.  Это  уже  имена  собствнные.  Если  конкретный  музей  в  каком-либо  городе  называется  литературным  без  дополнительного  определения ( областной, городской ),  то  тогда  Литературный  музей.  Если  определение  есть,  то  с  прописной  пишется  определение.  Таковы  правила.

Comment: Первый случай: музей называется официально \\Литературный музей\\.

Второй случай: музей называется официально, скажем, Казанский литературный музей. То есть это полное официальное название. 

Если хотим этот же музей (Казанский литературный музей) дальше в тексте назвать покороче, неполным названием - Литературный музей, нужно ли писать с прописной?

Comment: Думаю,  нет.  Хотя  и  от  контекста  зависит.  Если  автор  подчеркивает,  что  испытывает  большой  пиетет  к  этому  учреждению.  Но  так  можно  и  до  одного  слова  сократить.  В  нейтральном  для   для  данного  заведения  высказывании, да  ещё  после  полного  названия,   пишем  со  строчной.